# Why the music player stop playing music when taking photo?

Tags: camera, music-player, photos

May I know what is the reason why Android phone's music player will stop playing music when I switch to camera mode?

I find it logical if the music player stop playing music when taking a movie but stopping playing music when taking photo seems to be quite illogical since the photo taken will not save any sound.

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question, but I think that some people might find it useful since I came it across using Google search.

The camera app has a permission called *TAKE_AUDIO_FOCUS* which it is granted by default to it. The camera app uses this to pause the music while you open the viewfinder on your phone.

To fix this issue, you can simply disable the *TAKE_AUDIO_FOCUS* permission from your phone. The problem here is that you can't do it via the UI since the toggle for it isn't there.

The simplest way to not allow the camera app on your phone to pause your music is to take off this permission using the adb shell.

1. Download your OEM USB drivers from your phone's manufacturer's website. A simple Google search should give you the link.
2. Download [Minimal ADB portable](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=457095661767103465) and extract it to a folder on your desktop.
3. Connect your phone to your PC and enable USB Debugging. For that, Go to **Settings** > **About Phone** > **Tap on the Build Number 7 times**. This will unlock the Developer options on your phone. Now, Go to the **Developer mode** from Settings. **Enable USB Debugging**.
4. Now, open the folder where you extracted the Minimal ADB and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right-click on an empty space. From the context menu, select **Open Command Window Here**.
5. In the command window type `adb devices`.
6. Press **OK** on your Android phone when it asks you to give the permission for USB Debugging.
7. Now, type `adb shell` to open the command line interpreter on Android.
8. Type the following command to remove the `TAKE_AUDIO_FOCUS` permission from your Camera app:

   ```
   appops set app.package.name TAKE_AUDIO_FOCUS ignore
   ```

You will need to replace the *app.package.name* with the app's package name of the camera app in your Android phone. Since most manufacturers don't follow a single standard for naming their camera apps, you'll need to use a package info app from the Play Store to know the package name. Use [App inspector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubqsoft.sec01) for this.

Suppose your phone is a Moto G. You can type the following command to remove the `TAKE_AUDIO_FOCUS` permission

```
appops set com.motorola.cameraone TAKE_AUDIO_FOCUS ignore
```

That should be it.

**Source**: my own article [here](http://errorfixer.co/stop-camera-pausing-music-android-lollipop-above/).

Comment: For samsung phones the package name is `com.sec.android.app.camera`

Comment: For realme phones the package name is com.oppo.camera. And you will also have to enable the "Disable permission monitoring" in the developers options, otherwise adb will show SecurityException.

Comment: It works for capturing video too!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try installing a different camera app that does not take audio focus. I tried the [Camera MX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.magix.camera_mx) app for instance, and it does not appear to pause audio playback.